# No Ethernet or WIFI with 14.04 HP Pavilion

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

I have been trying for a month now. I would be super stoked if someone could help me:

```
scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ uname -a
Linux scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:227b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169


scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69509  8
bnep                   19624  2
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    72791  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    68937  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
uvcvideo               81073  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
btusb                  32497  0
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
bluetooth             446409  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
hp_wmi                 14109  0
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
intel_rapl             18783  0
intel_powerclamp       18823  0
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
coretemp               13441  0
snd_compress           19200  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      15172  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          30469  3
kvm                   452043  0
snd_hda_controller     31056  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         139682  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
crc32_pclmul           13133  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
joydev                 17393  0
snd_pcm               104112  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
serio_raw              13483  0
snd_seq_midi           13564  0
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
i915                  905798  3
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
rtsx_pci_ms            18168  0
mei_txe                19704  0
bcma                   52320  0
memstick               16966  1 rtsx_pci_ms
drm_kms_helper         61574  1 i915
mei                    87875  1 mei_txe
drm                   311018  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
lpc_ich                21093  0
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
iosf_mbi               13541  0
shpchp                 37047  0
wmi                    19193  1 hp_wmi
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    79468  19 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
i2c_hid                18726  0
hid                   110426  1 i2c_hid
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
video                  20128  1 i915
i2c_designware_platform    12979  0
hp_accel               26034  0
lis3lv02d              20156  1 hp_accel
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0
spi_pxa2xx_platform    23079  0
input_polldev          14607  1 lis3lv02d
parport_pc             32741  0
hp_wireless            12637  0
mac_hid                13227  0
dw_dmac                12835  0
dw_dmac_core           28390  1 dw_dmac
ppdev                  17671  0
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
8250_dw                13551  0
lp                     17759  0
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
pwm_lpss               13214  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23043  0
psmouse               106561  0
r8169                  71694  0
rtsx_pci               46259  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    13934  1 r8169
ahci                   34062  3
libahci                32424  1 ahci

scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

scotto@scotto-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:bf:9c:8e:1f:b7  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:25153 (25.1 KB)  TX bytes:25153 (25.1 KB)
```